# Python: Extract links in certain class' class

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

HTML:

```
            <li class="dropdown menu-large">
                <a href="/nephrology?cat=879" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="A">A<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
                                <li class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">    
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor:default;" title="A1">A1</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li><a href="/nephrology?p=3061" title="Apple">Apple</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/nephrology?p=3062" title="Alien">Alien</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/nephrology?p=3064" title="AI">AI</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/nephrology?p=3063" title="April">April</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown menu-large">
                <a href="/nephrology?cat=874" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="B">B<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu row">
                                <li class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="dropdown-header">

                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor:default;" title="B1">B1</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li><a href="/nephrology?p=3072" title="Banana">Banana</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/nephrology?p=3048" title="Babe">Babe</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/nephrology?p=3036" title="Bamboo">Bamboo</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="/nephrology?p=2771" title="Berry">Berry</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
            </li>
```

I want to scrape the urls of Apple, Alien, AI and April, but not sure how to do it. My code below only scraped A's url which is `"/nephrology?cat=879"`. How to let it scrape the url inside class' class `"divider"`? Because when I tried to use only class `"divider"`, it will also extract Banana's and others url. But I don't need them. Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'dropdown menu-large'}):
    for link in item.find_all('a', {'title' : 'A'}):
        href=link.get('href')   #it gets "/nephrology?cat=879"
```

Comment: Does you expected result include `Banana,Babe,Bamboo` as well?

Comment: @Shahin nope :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in following steps:

- First find all the `<li>` elements in the soup.

  ```
  soup.find_all("li")
  ```
- Then filter all the elements with only one child which is `a`

  ```
  len(list(soup_li.children)) == 1 and soup_li.a
  ```

Complete program can be visualized as:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("./sample.html", "r") as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')
    for soup_li in soup.find_all("li"):
        if len(list(soup_li.children)) == 1 and soup_li.a:
            print soup_li.a["href"]
```

Output:

> /nephrology?p=3061
>
> /nephrology?p=3062
>
> /nephrology?p=3064
>
> /nephrology?p=3063
>
> /nephrology?p=3072
>
> /nephrology?p=3048
>
> /nephrology?p=3036
>
> /nephrology?p=2771

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will produce the exact result you mentioned above.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

root = fromstring(html)
for title in root.cssselect(".dropdown:nth-child(1) .dropdown-header+.divider ~ li"):
    item = ' '.join([title.text for title in title.cssselect("a")])
    print(item)
```

Result:

```
Apple
Alien
AI
April
```